# Entity Framework: records in child table are not inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Records in parent table are saving successfully but child table records are not saving and no error is coming, using Entity Framework with repository pattern available [here](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com).

Below is the sample schema design of my tables, might be a special case.

[image]

Considering above tables if I try to insert records in Table2 and Table3 together no record inserted into Table3.

Please let me know if need further clarification on the question.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT 1**

Below is the code I am using to insert parent and child records together.

```
    var parent = new Table2()
    {
        Table1Id = 1,
        SecondColumn = 1
    };

    parent.Tables3.Add(new Table3()
    {
        Table1Id = 1,
        SecondColumn = 1,
        AnotherColumn = 1
    });

    context.Set<Table2>().Attach(parent);
    context.Entry<Table2>(parent).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT 2**

```
public partial class Table2
{
    public Table2()
    {
        this.Tables3 = new HashSet<Table3>();
    }

    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public int SecondColumn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Table3> Tables3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Table3
{
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public int SecondColumn { get; set; }
    public int AnotherColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is between Table1 and Table2 one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Can't  be answered without seeing (relevant parts of) the code that fails.

Comment: @BassamAlugili, yes its a 1to1 relationship.

Comment: @GertArnold It gives no error and no record in Table3 as well.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Whatever... it's your call. If you want an answer you have to do your due effort to get it.

Comment: @GertArnold have added sample code, sorry it took me long to identify the portion of the code that possibly creates the problem.

Comment: What's the relevance of table1 in the question?  Where is the source for the entity classes themselves?  It seems strange to go to the lengths you are since state tracking is usually handled for you.

Comment: @Russell Table1 is there to just give an idea how table structure is defined but the problem I am facing with is table2 and table3 hierarchical record.

Comment: So let's see the poco class declarations?

Comment: Kirill's number 1 was what I was going to suggest you try

Answer (score 1):

You should do one of two:

1. Use add instead of attach

   ```
   var parent = new Table2()
   {
       Table1Id = 1,
       SecondColumn = 1
   };

   parent.Tables3.Add(new Table3()
   {
       Table1Id = 1,
       SecondColumn = 1,
       AnotherColumn = 1
   });

   context.Set<Table2>().Add(parent);
   context.SaveChanges();
   ```

In this case all navigation properties will also be added.

2. Paint your whole graph with state after attach (now you set state only to parent table).